# Looker measure error - raw sql results do not include filled-in values for

Tags: looker, lookml

I have a pdt that generates several dimensions and a measure which is simply an integer which is a pre computed count for that dimension combination.

After implementing the explore I went to test that the data is working in the 'Explore' capability and received the error:

> raw sql results do not include filled-in values for

The measure is of type 'number'

It looks like in the resulting raw SQL query it is attempting to do a group by but is assuming it needs to include the measure I have in the group by which is incorrect I really just want it to add the measure values for that group together.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the way to fix this is to define the measure as type: 'sum' instead of as a number.

What this is telling looker is that when it creates some summary table and queries your database that if this measure is returned and is not in the group by then how would you like to combine multiple rows.